# CSS border not being applied fully

Tags: css, html, border

Here is my code:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
#home {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="vari" href="..." id="home"><span>Home</span></a> 
    </li>
    <li><a class="vari" href="">Music videos</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The “Music videos” text doesn’t get a full border but something and the “Home” text doesn’t get any border — why?

I want a border and a width of 800px for both of them.

Comment: try removing margin-left:-35px

Comment: Check the snippets below, it works

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/nwua4eko/1/

Comment: yes thank you :D what is this site everyone seems to be so helpful and want to help, i just started programming

Comment: ohh..sorry i don't know that answer is already given in comment.. sorry again for giving answer.

Comment: @Leothelion don't worry about it, I wasn't entirely sure what waleedd32 was after which is why I wanted to clarify in the comments.

Comment: well i guess by his  same comment under all answer so i got to know that he wanted border on ul not on li and in left like menu so.. thanx for nice reply :)

Comment: @waleedd32 No problem. Just a pointer for now and future questions, if Leo's answer helped you should consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avo9qak3/3/). As you need both menu in one line so i used `display:inline-block` on a and border on `ul`. Hope this will solve your issue. Ty

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin-left property:

```
#home {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Try to check this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVwdXj

Comment: no like that i want them to be next to each other and both to be in one border

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/5n6e5vx9/ .Remove margin-left from home id

```
#home {
position:relative;
//margin-left:-35px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: o like that i want them to be next to each other and both to be in one border

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/avo9qak3/2/)

Css Code:

```
  ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
#home {
   position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
}
#music
{
   text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: i want those texts to be next to each other and inside one border not two borders

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-left:-35px;` as this property is keeping 'Home' out of the border.

Comment: i want those texts to be next to each other and inside one border not two separate borders

Comment: Use **display:inline;** then instead of **display:inline-block;** Consult [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal) for demonstration